# Joining two insulators at different potentials with a conductor

Tags: electric-current, voltage, conductors, insulators

If two insulators are connected by a conducting wire, will the charges flow if they are different potentials?

According to me, as the charges can't enter the insulators, charges only get distributed at the ends of the conductor to overcome the field due to the potential difference of the insulators.

Please verify and explain with a real life example if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The wire will equalise the potential between the contact points on the insulators. It cannot do any more than that, because the insulators will not conduct. Because they cannot conduct, charge cannot flow from other parts of the insulators, and hence they will stay at their original potential.

EDIT
I should add that there is no such thing as a perfect insulator. All substances conduct some current. We call it an insulator when the conduction is negligible. If the voltage is high enough, a conductor will also "break down" and start conducting.

Comment: Can you mention a source of what you have mentioned?

Comment: I can't really think of any source that details your specific question, i.e. the travel of charge across an insulator, but have a look at https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-1/Conductors-and-Insulators